# Selenium launch browser in specific path (for example ./firefox/firefox.exe) (Python3)

Tags: python, selenium, firefox

I would like to do what is in the title.
My code:

```
from selenium import webdriver
driver = webdriver.Firefox()
driver.get('https://www.google.com')
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Have you tried webdriver-manager library?
It's amazing, you just need to install it:

```
pip install webdriver-manager
```

and launch your code like this:

```
from selenium import webdriver
from webdriver_manager.firefox import GeckoDriverManager
driver = webdriver.Firefox(executable_path=GeckoDriverManager().install())
```

that package downloads you needed geckodriver automatically. Don't forget path 'executable_path' while launching driver.
As well you can you chromedriver, like that:

```
from selenium import webdriver
from webdriver_manager.chrome import ChromeDriverManager
driver = webdriver.Chrome(ChromeDriverManager().install())
```

Comment: @Bob may you please, confirm my answer like solved, I get reputation to upvote your question.

Answer (score 0):

Selenium searches the webdriver through the directories on sys.path, so you would first have to do something like that:

```
import sys
from selenium import webdriver
sys.path.insert(0,'/path/to/firefox')
driver = webdriver.Firefox()
driver.get('https://www.google.com')
```